# How can I make launchers for to two different Firefox profiles on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firefox-profile

On my Ubuntu machine, I'd like to use two Firefox profiles simultaneously. I know I can run this command in terminal twice:

```
firefox -ProfileManager -no-remote
```

or run `about:profiles` on browser and each time choose a separate profile. But that's kind of cumbersome. So I'm wondering if there is a way to make separate launchers for each profile?

Comment: Try `firefox -P profile-name`. I think it isn't worth a dedicated answer, because this is directly answered in the `firefox --help`.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov But it is a correct answer. Just do it. And add a [Wiki link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions#-P_.22profile_name.22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `firefox --help`:

```
Firefox options
...
  -P <profile>       Start with <profile>.
  --profile <path>   Start with profile at <path>.
...
```

Use `firefox -P profile-name` in the launcher.

Comment: I'm aware of this command but  I'd like to make GUI launcher icon for this, to avoid need to get to terminal to do so. Modified the title to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Create a new lanucher icon and enter the command into it. This is how launchers are created.

Comment: Works great, thank for your tip Nikita.

Comment: Please accept an answer then, for new generations so see this question as having a working answer, and for it to not to float around as not answered.